# Java String - How to make fuction which add String into String?

Tags: java, string

I want to make function which add String into String

I tried like this:

in main fuction

```
String text = "";
addLine(text, "line1");
```

in addLine(String text, String line)

```
text += line;
text += "\n";
```

I know += operation between String make new instance in java.
But, upper code does not work.

How can i make function which add String to String?

Comment: what doesn't work in the `upper code`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
  public String addLine(String one, String two){
    return one+two;
}
```

Note, this returns a string, so in main do something like:

```
text = addLine(text, "line1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create it as a method:

---

```
public class Text {
private String text = "Hello";
public Text(){}
public Text(String text){
    this.text = text;
}
public void setText(String text){
    this.text = text;
}
public void addLine(String lnToAdd){
    text += "\n" +lnToAdd ;
}
public String getText(){
    return text;
}
```

}

---

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Text text = new Text("Hello");
    System.out.println(text.getText()); //Returns Hello
    System.out.println();
    text.addLine("Java");
    System.out.println(text.getText()); /*Returns Hello
                                                  Java*/
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply!